# Correct this problem in complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification

> Prove for all $|z| = 3$, $$\frac{8}{11} \leq \left | \frac{z^2 + 1}{z^2 + 2}\right | \leq \frac{10}{7}.$$

Here is what I did,

$$\frac{8}{11}\leq \frac{8}{z^2 + 2}=\frac{|z^2| - 1}{z^2 +2}\leq\left | \frac{z^2 + 1}{z^2 + 2} \right |= \left | \frac{z^2}{z^2+ 2} + \frac{1}{z^2+2} \right | \leq \left | \frac{z^2}{z^2+ 2} \right | + \left | \frac{1}{z^2+ 2} \right | =  \frac{|z^2|}{z^2 + 2} + \frac{1}{z^2 + 2} = \frac{10}{z^2 + 2 } \leq \frac{10}{9} \leq \frac{10}{7}$$

If i misused any properties, typo or not, can you identify them for me?

Comment: Note $\frac{8}{11} \leq \frac{8}{z^2+2}$ has no meaning unless $z$ is a real number. For an arbitrary complex number $z$ we cannot write this in equality.

Comment: You missed a modulus in the denominator of the second fraction, it should be $|z|^2+2$ but then the inequality $|z|^2+2 \geq |z^2+2|$ needs to be established.

Comment: @PaulSundheim, you mean $\frac{8}{|z^2|} \leq\frac{|z^2| - 1}{|z^2 +2|}\leq\left | \frac{z^2 + 1}{z^2 + 2} \right |$

Comment: @sidht What I was hinting to the questioner was that they should show that ${8}\over{11}$ = ${|z|^2-1}\over{|z|^2+2}$ $\leq ...$

Comment: I am the questioner, but I got this from a book I found.

Comment: But the statement $8/11 \leq \frac{8}{|z^2|}$ is false

Comment: @PaulSundheim, where did you get that from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$8=|z^2|-1\leq |z^2+1|\leq |z^2|+1=10$ and  $7=|z^2|-|2|\leq |z^2+2|\leq |z^2|+2=11$

Comment: So for the upper bound, $$\frac{10}{|z^2 + 2|} \leq \frac{10}{|z|^2 - 2}?$$

Answer (score 1):

You should not have expression involving $z$ without absolute value signs. For example, the statement $$\frac{8}{11} \leq \frac{8}{z^2+2}$$ makes no sense as $\mathbb{C}$ is not an ordered field, while $$\frac{8}{11} \leq \frac{8}{|z|^2+2}$$ does make sense (and is true), as $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field.

Taking this into consideration, you have successfully shown $$\frac{8}{11} \leq \left|\frac{z^2 + 1}{z^2 + 2}\right| \leq \frac{10}{|z^2 + 2|}.$$ You then claim $$\frac{10}{|z^2 + 2|} \leq \frac{10}{9}.$$ I don't see how you obtained this. Instead, you should use the reverse triangle inequality on $|z^2 + 2|$ to obtain the desired upper bound for the given expression.

Comment: Yeah the last inequality, I treated $z \in \mathbb{R}$, which isn't  right because for some reason I thought $|z|^2 = z^2.$

Answer (score 1):

You can establish a slighly stronger inequality by noticing that $|z|=3$ implies $|z^2+2|\in[7,11]$, hence:
$$\left|\frac{z^2+1}{z^2+2}\right|=\left|1-\frac{1}{z^2+2}\right|\in\left[\frac{6}{7},\frac{12}{11}\right].$$

Comment: Would mind checking my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Like [For all complex numbers with $|z|=2$, inequality $2\le |z-4|\le 6$ holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879075/for-all-complex-numbers-with-z-2-inequality-2-le-z-4-le-6-holds/879294#879294),

$\displaystyle z=3(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\implies z^2=9(\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta)$

$\displaystyle\left|\frac{z^2+1}{z^2+2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{82+18\cos2\theta}{85+36\cos2\theta}}$

Now clearly, the maximum and minimum values of  $\displaystyle\frac{82+18\cos2\theta}{85+36\cos2\theta}=\frac12+\frac{79}{2(85+36\cos2\theta)}$ are attainable at $\cos2\theta=-1,1$ respectively which are $\displaystyle\frac{82+18(-1)}{85+36(-1)}=\left(\frac87\right)^2$ and $\displaystyle\frac{82+18(+1)}{85+36(+1)}=\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^2$ respectively

Comment: @sidht, How about this?

Comment: Can you explain the "clearly, the maximum and" part…?

Comment: @sidht, 
$\displaystyle\frac{82+18\cos2\theta}{85+36\cos2\theta}$ will be maximum iff $\displaystyle\frac1{85+36\cos2\theta}$ is maximum iff $\cos2\theta$ is minimum , right?

Comment: I am not following the second iff

Comment: @sidht, Please pinpoint your confusion

Comment: Why is finding the maximizers for $\displaystyle\frac{82+18\cos2\theta}{85+36\cos2\theta}$ the same as $\displaystyle\frac{1}{85+36\cos2\theta}$

Comment: @sidht, The relation $$\displaystyle\frac{82+18\cos2\theta}{85+36\cos2\theta}=\frac12+\frac{79}{2(85+36\cos2\theta)}$$ can be generalized as $$f(\theta)=A+Bg(\theta)$$ where $A,B$ are constants. So, the maxima of $f,g$ will be at same value of $\theta$